Cannot send api req in github codespaces
I am trying to build a keystonejs app in the github codespaces but when the default keystone nextjs app trying to fetch requests to the server it's always giving a 400 response. I have tried the graphql playground it's working good.
I need a way to get a valid response from the server so the nextjs app works fine.

Add a code snippet so we can see what you are doing. Unless we know what you are doing, we can't know where you went wrong. Make your code snippet the smallest amount of code that shows the error. (Sometimes, the process of making the smallest possible example shows you where your error was.)
